# compare two excel files in a ssis "Foreach Loop Container"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

**Introduction :** I have Multiple Excel files which loop through a `Foreach Loop Container` in SSIS Package.

1. The first Excel file `Excel1.xlsx` contains the old data (**for example** :I have a column named `EffectiveDate` populated with `2001-01-01` to `2013-04-01`of
2. The second Excel file `Excel2.xlsx` contains the new entries with `EffectiveDate` from `2013-05-01` and also contains some old data from `Excel1.xlsx`.
3. These two files loop through `Foreach Loop Container`.

**Problem :** Once the first Excel file `Excel1.xlsx` is loaded , i want to compare  it with second Excel file `Excel2.xlsx` and update  the `EffectiveDate` of **old data** in `Excel2.xlsx` with `EffectiveDate` of **matching rows** in `Excel1.xlsx`
And all other rows( or new Entires) of `Excel2.xlsx` with `GetDate()`.

Is it possible to get it done in a single `Data Flow Task`? 
And also how do i compare two excel files in a single container?

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 Excel sources within one data flow task.  You could use a merge join to compare the values, and feed that to an excel output.

If you want to loop through 10 excel files, comparing 1 to another, I would suggest that your merge join output be the 2nd excel source, and map your container variable to the first excel source. That way, Everything from Excel file 1 will be put into the output file, then for each subsequent file only the entries not listed already in the output file will be added.

If you get hung up on any of the steps individually I'm sure myself or others can help you push through the sticking points.

Comment: Thank you , i am trying to implement in the procedure you said to me, i will get back to you once the task is accomplished